# How to read specific column in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am new to pyspark. I want to read specific column from input file. I know how to do this in pandas

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv',usecols=[0,1,2])
```

But Is there any functionality similar to this operation in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a CSV file is usually not as straight-forward as @zlidime's answer suggests.

What if the row has `;` characters in the column content? Then you need to parse the quotes, and know in advance what the quoting character is.
Or maybe you want to skip the header, or parse it to have the column names.

Instead, as mentioned [here](http://www.sparktutorials.net/Opening+CSV+Files+in+Apache+Spark+-+The+Spark+Data+Sources+API+and+Spark-CSV) you can use [dataframes](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-python.html)

`df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("te2.csv")`

And to query the columns, you can use:

`df.col("col_1").cast("int")`

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use map to select specific columns

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ReadCSV")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)
df=sc.textFile("te2.csv") \
   .map(lambda line: line.split(";")) \
   .map(lambda line: (line[0],line[3])) \
   .toDF()
```