# How to read selected columns while reading csv file in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: csv, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to read selected columns while reading the csv file. Suppose csv file has 10 columns but I want to read only 5 columns. Is there any way to do this?

Pandas we can use `usecols` but is there any option available in pyspark also?

Pandas :

```
df=pd.read_csv(file_path,usecols=[1,2],index_col=0)
```

Pyspark :

```
?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read specific column in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240782/how-to-read-specific-column-in-pyspark)

Comment: But how to read directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the first 5 columns, you can select the first 5 columns after reading the whole CSV file:

```
df = spark.read.csv(file_path, header=True)
df2 = df.select(df.columns[:5])
```

Comment: can we use 'select' option while reading the csv file?

Comment: I don't think so. However, that will not cause performance degradation because the CSV file is lazily read. Only the first 5 columns will be read because you only selected the first 5 columns.

Comment: but reading the file first and then select 5 columns. I think this process will also take some time.

Comment: The file is not read because of lazy evaluation of Spark, so it will not take time.